# How do I assign Instagram redirect uri in python social auth?

Tags: oauth, python-social-auth

I am using [python-social-auth](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and trying to implement login with Instagram.

In the [documentation](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/instagram.html) they tell only to fill the following values:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_SECRET = ''
```

I filled those in but when I tried to login with instagram I got this error:

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}
```

In my developer account, I registered `REDIRECT URI` as `http://localhost:8000`.

How can I tell `python-social-auth` to use `http://localhost:8000` as redirect uri???

I tried these but they did not help:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8000/'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't fix it like that, it's better to change the redirect uri within your instagram developer account. The reason is that every backend needs it's own endpoint or python social auth won't know which one to send it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was suggested by @Wolph it is better to change the redirect uri within my instagram developer account to match the endpoint of python social auth.

So, `http://localhost:8000/complete/instagram` helped.